# Graph API shows Canvas items in Graph Explorer but not returned by PHP SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm retrieving posts from a page via the PHP SDK (version 5.0.0). The third post in the feed is a Canvas item and is being returned by the Graph Explorer:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=578588098993907%2Fposts%3Ffields%3Did%26limit%3D20&version=v2.8

[image: graph explorer]

Canvas items:
https://www.facebook.com/business/news/introducing-canvas
Note canvas items are only displayed on mobile and not on desktop - might be related.

When I retrieve the latest posts from the page via the PHP SDK the canvas post is completely ommitted :

```
$request = $this->client->request('GET', 
                                  '/578588098993907/posts',
                                   array('limit' => 10, 'fields' => id));
$response = $this->client->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge(); 
foreach ($graphEdge as $graphNode) {
    echo $graphNode->getField('id');
}
```

(code simplified)

Gives:

```
578588098993907_578950888957628
578588098993907_578951082290942
578588098993907_578945485624835
578588098993907_578665362319514
578588098993907_578662648986452
578588098993907_578660458986671
578588098993907_578659585653425
578588098993907_578633098989407
578588098993907_578632585656125
578588098993907_578631848989532
```

The canvas post with ID 578588098993907_578950478957669 is completely omitted from the results.

Comment: I don't even see it in Graph API Explorer, and requesting the specific post id only gives me _"Unsupported get request. Object with ID '578588098993907_578950478957669' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation."_ which most of the time is indeed a permissions problem, resp. a matter of which type of access token is used. I have no experience with those canvas items yet (what an unlucky naming choice, considering that _canvas apps_ have existed in the FB universe for years - that's gonna lead to some confusion), [...]

Comment: [...] but I assume publishing them involves an app at some point? If so, first of all check if that app is set public yet.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I published it via the normal page management on facebook.com, not via any app. I've checked that it appears in the page feed on mobile (on the facebook app) when logged in with a completely separate facebook account, so it's definitely published.

Comment: The fact that you can't see it using the Graph API explorer is interesting. I suspect it might be showing up for me because I published the post originally, but I'm also retrieving the posts via the PHP SDK with an access token that's linked to my account, so I still can't see why the behaviour would be different. Agreed on the unfortunate choice of names!

Comment: I haven't checked if any API documentation regarding those canvas items exists yet, but if it doesn't, or doesn't offer an explanation to what's happening here, then I suggest you file a bug report and ask them for clarification. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/